# My selenium browser won't close in Python

Tags: python, selenium, proxy

I'm trying to create a class that will have methods to test http proxies one by one until I have a working one that I can add to to a selenium webdriver instance.

I have a raw_input to verify that the proxy is working in the webdriver, if it isn't working it should test another proxy and ask for confirmation from me and then either close the driver or stay open. (I removed the if statement that uses the test method because I was getting an error)

When I enter 'n' in terminal when I get asked for confirmation it closes the browser and opens another one with another proxy but when I enter 'n' a second time the browser stays open.

```
class Driver:

    def test(self):
        try:
            urllib.urlopen(
                "https://www.google.com",
                proxies={'http': proxy}
            )
            return True
        except IOError:
            print "Connection error! (Check proxy)"
        else:
            return False

    def get_driver(self):
        proxies = []
        with open('working_proxies.txt', 'rb') as working_proxies:
            for proxy in working_proxies:
                proxy.rstrip()
                proxies.append(proxy.decode('ascii'))
        for i in proxies:
            try:
                myproxy = proxies.pop()
                proxy   = Proxy({
                              'proxyType': ProxyType.MANUAL,
                              'httpProxy': myproxy,
                              'ftpProxy': myproxy,
                              'sslProxy': myproxy,
                              'noProxy': '' # set this value as desired
                              })
                driver = webdriver.Firefox(proxy=proxy)
                is_working = raw_input('Is your proxy working? [y/n]: ')
                if is_working == 'y' or is_working == 'Y':
                    return driver
                if is_working == 'n' or is_working == 'N':
                    driver.close()
                    continue
                if not is_working == 'y' or is_working == 'Y' or is_working == 'n' or is_working == 'N':
                    print 'Invallid'
            except:
                continue

driver = Driver()
driver = driver.get_driver()
driver.get("https://www.google.com")
```

Comment: why not use selenium and assertions to identify a working proxy, rather than requiring raw input?

Answer (score 0):

You can try `driver.quit()` instead of `driver.close()`